# CosmosDb stored procedure call

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to create some generic stored procedures and some use-case specific stored procedures in CosmosDB. Is it possible to call generic stored procedures from within use-case specific ones?

Comment: I think what you need is generic UDFs and use-case specific stored procedures.

Comment: Hi,maybe it's off-topic question here. You need to post more details about your solution. Such as what you have done, what error you met, any block you got.

Comment: Hi,any progress here?

Comment: @JayGong Thanks for help. Give me sometime I will update this thread

Comment: @Akshat Sure! please post more details so that I'll try to help you!